# What is the differences between del list[i] and list =list[:i] + list[i+1:]?

Tags: python, list, slice

So the question is to delete an element at position i in a list, what are the differences between the following actions?

```
i = 3
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
del l[i]
```

```
i = 3
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
l = l[:i] + l[i+1:]
```

Both ways give the list the same result. But what are the essential differences?
Why is the second operation not acceptable?

Comment: The first one modifies the list in place, the second one creates a new list.

Comment: first one deleting element at index `i` , 2nd one creating new list by excluding element at index `i`

Comment: "Why is the second operation not acceptable?" where it is not acceptable?

Comment: The difference is relevant if there are other references to the list. Those other references won't be updated.

Comment: And there are also performance implications for large lists. The second one uses more memory temporarily.

Comment: As for what is "acceptable", that depends on who gave you the requirement. We can't read your instructor's mind.

Answer (score 4):

> But what are the essential differences?

The `del` way modifies the list in place. This means that *any other* names for that list will have the change reflected:

```
i = 3
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
k = l
del l[i]
# k has changed
```

The `id()` of the list does not change, because it is still the same list - only its contents have changed (just like if you used e.g. `.append` or `.pop`, or assigned to an element).

The slicing way creates a new list. This means that other names for the list will *not* have the change reflected - because they are still names for the original list, and that list was never changed.

```
i = 3
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
k = l
l = l[:i] + l[i+1:]
# k has not changed
```

If there are no other names for the original list, then the slicing way allows for the original list to be garbage-collected. The new list will probably not have the same `id()` as the original, because the old list's contents have to stick around during construction of the new one. There will be a temporary spike in the amount of memory used, which may matter for some programs with millions of elements in the list (or with elements that are very large objects).

If there *are* other names for the original list, then the new list will have a different `id()`, because it is a different list and the original still exists.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is to delete an element at position `i` in a list

not

"to create another list without element `i`". That's why the second operation is not acceptable